# How to put a stored procedure results to a table and truncate results every time the stored procedure is executed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, database-administration

I have a stored procedure that runs with a SSRS Report that generates a report daily for users. What I am trying to accomplish is to capture yesterday's records from the stored procedure and compare them with today's data to get variance. See the screenshot below.

I have modified the stored procedure to get yesterday's records but I need assistance how to put those records/results from the stored procedure into a table for variance comparison.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `INSERT INTO... EXEC`?

Comment: maybe a `TRUNCATE TABLE` somewhere too.

Comment: It seems you simply want to create a single resultset that contains information for "today" and for "yesterday". A simple query using conditional aggregation (search for it) can do that if you want a single row per "entity" that contains both values.

Comment: Is it not possible to insert the data inside of the Stored Procedure?

Comment: Simply use the same table twice for comparison using the [INSTERSECT and/or EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) keywords.

Comment: Thank you !  INSERT INTO & EXEC worked for me  . supplying the right parameters to SP was the issue on loading the records to a  table created .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ! INSERT INTO & EXEC worked for me . supplying the right parameters to SP was the issue on loading the records to a table created .